# Web deploy tool customization

Tags: c#, msdeploy, webdeploy

Can we add hyperlink on web deploy tool which check on my server following prerequisite?

1..Net Framework 4.5 installed or not.
2. MVC framework installed or not.
3. Connectivity to database server from Web Server.

```
My application is in MVC 2?
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a batch script to assert these things and run it from the prompt:

`msdeploy.exe -preSync="myAssertions.bat" ...`

the preSync command will be executed on the remote server. Note: the batch file you will execute here needs to reside on the server because as the command specifies; *preSync* no syncing has happened yet.

More information about the preSync provider: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619740(v=ws.10).aspx